# "pnpm -F "@packages/core" install" Why download all the dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, pnpm

My expectation with this command is to install only the dependencies under "@packages/core",But all the projects in the workspace are installed

[image]

```
pnpm -F "@packages/core" install
```

[image]